# Qatar economy booking classes

Tags: air-travel, price, qatar-airways, fare-class

Qatar Airways advertises "[fare families](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-us/fare-families.html)" to make it easy to see what is allowed, allowed for a charge, or not allowed with a particular fare:

- Promo Fare
- Saver Fare
- Value Fare
- Flexi Fare

But which booking class codes book into which fare types? The economy fare codes are B, H, Y, V, L, K, M, O, T, N, Q, S.

Answer (score 2):

The Qatar Privilege Club [earning chart](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-us/Privilege-Club/earn-qmiles/qmiles-earn-chart.html) indicates the following:

**First**

- Flexi: F
- Value: P
- Saver: A
- Promo: A

**Business**

- Flexi: J, C
- Value: D
- Saver: I
- Promo: R

**Economy**

- Flexi: Y, B, H
- Value: K, M, L, V
- Saver: S, N, Q
- Promo: T, O, W
- Group or Tour: G

Note however that sometimes Qatar issues Economy Saver as O, T classes, which can lead to complications in Qmiles / QPoints accrual